# Multiple laravel on demo server

Tags: php, laravel

I have a LAMP server. I can reach the www folder with a domain (let's say) `something.domain.com:1234`.
The projects I usually work is written with Laravel. I can set them up on my localhost easily with `virtualhost` in XAMPP. The question is, how can I set them up on my demo server?

For example there are 2 Laravel projects.

```sh
   www/project1
   www/project2
```

On localhost they work like `project1.localhost`, `project2.localhost`.
How can I make it with a real server with a domain?
The main problem is with the public folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Nginx or Apache?

Comment: I'm using Apache both on the server and on my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a config sample of my vhosts on Apache2 :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainname.ext
    DocumentRoot \path\to\laravel\public
    <Directory  "\path\to\laravel\public">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And for my local environnement, I add to to the host file a new entry (work like a local DNS ) :

```
127.0.0.1 domainname.ext
```

The host file are :

- Windows : `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- Linux/Mac : `/etc/hosts`

PS : you can do it for any IP address

Comment: Um, yeah thanks for that. But if I set it on my demo server. How can I reach it? I mean the domainname.ext in your example. I don't want to setup a new domain for every new project. I just would like to have it like something.domain.com:1234/project1, something.domain.com:1234/project2.